Why epitaxially grown quantum well layers are thin compared to barrier layers?
When quantum wells (QWs) are grown, e.g., with molecular beam epitaxy (MBE), the quantum well layers are very thin compared to barrier layers. For example, in AlGaAs-GaAs-AlGaAs structure the AlGaAs layers are much thicker compared to the GaAs QWs. Why?

You should explain what you mean by "barrier layer".

A symmetric potential well is created is by sandwiching a lower band gap material (GaAs) between a higher band gap material (AlGaAs). The depth of the well is the difference between the band gaps of GaAs and AlGaAs. The width of the potential well is the thickness of the GaAs layer. To take advantage of quantum effects (quantum tunneling) and create an narrow isolated potential well, the GaAs layer is much thinner than the AlGaAs layers.
